# Create a signed URL

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, amazon-web-services

Does anyone know how to create a signed URL using VB .Net? Ive had a look around but nothing out there to guide me in what to do/use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [AWS SDK for .Net](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/), which is available on NuGet.

Call `AmazonS3Client.GetPreSignedURL()`.

Comment: Im using the Product Advertising API and writing this in code..... Ive installed the SDK but not sure what steps to take next?

Comment: In case it makes a difference i started by adding a service reference to http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl

Comment: That's a completely different question.  http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/3941 http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/2480 http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/2481